# Вращение прямоугольника вокруг своего центра

Tags: c++, winapi

Рисую прямоугольник, используя средства `WinAPI`. Как вращаю:

```
    POINT pi; // структура точка
    // Определяю центр прямоугольника
    pt.x = (начало отрезка + конец отрезка) / 2;
    pt.y = (начало отрезка по вертикали + конец отрезка) / 2;

   // координаты хранятся в двух массивах coordinate_x и _y соответственно
   for (int i(0); i < 4; i++)
        {
            // вычитаю из каждой точки центр прямоугольника
            coordinate_x[i] -= pt.x; coordinate_y[i] -= pt.y;

            // поворачиваю точку по формулам:
            // xNew = x * Cos(A) + y * Sin(A)
            // yNew = y * Cos(A) - x * Sin(A)
            // _gradus - подаётся в градусах, поэтому конвертирую в радианы

            int new_x = cos(_gradus * (PI / 180))*coordinate_x[i] - sin(_gradus * (PI / 180)) * coordinate_y[i];
            int new_y = sin(_gradus * (PI / 180)) * coordinate_x[i] + cos(_gradus * (PI / 180))*coordinate_y[i];

            // прибавляю к повернутой точке центр прямоугольника и записываю обратно в массив
            coordinate_x[i] = pt.x + new_x; coordinate_y[i] = pt.y + new_y;
        }
```

Уже затем вновь отрисовываю. Но вращение идёт вокруг левой верхней точки. Где я ошибся?

Comment: Что такое  `начало отрезка + конец отрезка`? Что такое `начало отрезка по вертикали + конец отрезка`? Как вы это умудрились скомпилировать?

Comment: pt.x = (coord_left_x + coord_right_x) / 2;
     pt.y = (coord_top_y + coord_bottom_y) / 2;
Вот, подойдёт? Можно предположить, основываясь на структуру RECT(прямоугольник).

Comment: Ну а теперь что такое `coord_left_x`, `coord_right_x`, `coord_top_y`, `coord_bottom_y`? Откуда взяты эти значения? Если у вас в этих значениях чушь, то и вращаться все будет вокруг неправильной точки. Почему очевиднейше *критически важная* информация отсутствует в тексте вопроса?

Comment: Прошу прощения. Координаты получаю в зависимости от размеров окна. coord_left_x = размер окна по x /4 ; coord_right_x = размер окна по x - coord_left_x; coord_top_y = размер окна по y / 4; coord_bottom_y = размер окна по y - coord_top_y. Таким образом прямоугольник отрисовывается всегда в центре. Координаты окон получаю в пикселях, по событию WM_SIZE.

Comment: Ничего не понимаю. Согласно вашему коду, ваш "прямоугольник" хранится в массивах `coordinate_x[]` и `coordinate_y[]`. Так при чем здесь какое-то размеры окна? И при чем здесь, еще раз, эти переменные? Как они связаны с массивами `coordinate_x[]` и `coordinate_y[]`?

Comment: Быть может,  приведу полностью код?

Comment: "Но вращение идёт вокруг левой верхней точки" -- обычный признак того, что центр вращения не был перемещен в начало координат. Почитайте про матрицу преобразований. Матрица поворота получается из [последовательного умножения 3х матриц](http://sernam.ru/book_mm3d.php?id=45): "матрица сдвига центра вращения в начало координат", "матрица поворота на определенный угол" и "матрица обратного сдвига центра вращения". Либо можете использовать готовую матрицу.

Comment: @mega буквально час назад нашёл статью, прочитал, понял. Сделал, всё заработало, но прямоугольник начал терять масштаб. Но, покопавшись, понял, что в одном месте float неявно приводился к int, отсюда и потери. Ох, весь мир построен на матрицах, и сегодня в этом убедился..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Но вращение идёт вокруг левой верхней точки

Обычный признак того, что центр вращения не был перемещен в начало координат. Проще всего использовать [матрицу преобразований (матрица перехода)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

[Матрица поворота](http://sernam.ru/book_mm3d.php?id=45) получается из последовательного [умножения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873134.aspx) 3х матриц:

1. матрица сдвига центра вращения в начало координат
2. матрица поворота на определенный угол
3. матрица обратного сдвига центра вращения

[image]

Либо можете использовать готовую матрицу поворота вокруг произвольной точки:

[image]

В формулах `{x, y}` - Ваши исходные координаты прямоугольника (или любой другой произвольной фигуры), а `{x*, y*}` - конечные координаты уже повернутой фигуры вокруг точки `{m, n}`. Угол задается в радианах.

На картинках упрощенная формула. На самом деле конечные координаты будут в векторе `{x*, y*, h}`: вместо единицы - дополнительная компонента - `h`. Привычные нам, декартовы координаты из этого вектора можно получить так: `{x*/h, y*/h}`, т.е. делим все 3 компоненты на `h`.